# Get predicted values for next period

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

please consider following data:

```
y<- c(2,2,6,3,2,23,5,6,4,23,3,4,3,87,5,7,4,23,3,4,3,87,5,7)
x1<- c(3,4,6,3,3,23,5,6,4,23,6,5,5,1,5,7,2,23,6,5,5,1,5,7)
x2<- c(7,3,6,3,2,2,5,2,2,2,2,2,6,5,4,3,2,3,2,2,6,5,4,3)

type <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")
generation<- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4)
year<-         c(2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011)
data        <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,model,generation,year)
```

I would now make analysis that only take into account each single year and predict on the following. So in essence, this would run several separate analysis, only taking into account the data up to one point in time and then predicting on the next (only the directly next) period.

I tried to set up an example for the three models:

```
data2004 <- subset(data, year==2004)
data2005 <- subset(data, year==2005)
m1 <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=data2004)
preds <- predict(m1, data2005)
```

How can I do this automatically? My preferred output would be a predicted value for each type that indicates what the value would have been for each of the values that exist in the following period (the original data has 200 periods).

Thanks in advance, help very much appreciated!

Comment: What does `model` reference in the above code? I get `object 'model' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be more like what you want.

```
uq.year <- sort(unique(dat$year)) ## sorting so that i+1 element is the year after ith element
year <- dat$year
dat$year <- NULL ## we want everything in dat to be either the response or a predictor

model <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times = length(year) / 3) ## identifies the separate people per year

predlist <- vector("list", length(uq.year) - 1) ## there is 1 prediction fewer than the number of unique years

for(i in 1:(length(uq.year) - 1))
{
  mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = subset(dat, year == uq.year[i]))
  predlist[[i]] <- predict(mod, subset(dat, subset = year == uq.year[i + 1], select = -y))      
  names(predlist[[i]]) <- model[year == uq.year[i + 1]] ## labeling each prediction
}
```

The reason that we want `dat` to only have modeling variables (rather than `year`, for example) is because then we can easily use the `y ~ .` notation and avoid having to spell out all of the predictors in the `lm` call.

Comment: Hi Chaconne, thanks for the answer. The "model" variable is actually the one that specifies which to predict and is nominal. Is there a way to connected the variable with the results? E.g., model with the predictions that we got?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean. Do you mean that `model` indicates which model-fitting function should be used? Or do you mean that `model` indicates which years to predict? Could you give an example of what `head(model)` would look like?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: the variable "model" indicates "a", "b", "c". Three predictions are made for the years which correspond to "a", "b", "c", e.g., three persons for each periods exist which are indicated by this variable. Can I somehow add to the output for which person the output is predicted? thanks so much: > head(predlist)
[[1]]
  a  b  c 
3.6 4.0 3.6

Comment: I've updated my answer based upon what I think you're looking for. Each of the three predictions per year is now labeled "a", "b", or "c" depending upon its value in `model`. Does this help?